# Falcon Shield Attachment

Tags: piece-information, building, connections

If I want to attach the [Falcon shield](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3846pb055#T=C) to a wall, what kind of attachment do I need? I suspect I need a horizontal clip but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a horizontal clip won't work because on the back the shield has both a vertical and a horizontal bar and the horizontal one will be in the way. The way Lego uses to attach this kind of shields to a wall is to use a [Brick, Modified 1 x 1 with Stud on Side](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87087#T=C) and put the horizontal bar of the shield into the hole of the previously mentioned brick.